# ArrayList equivalent for a swap method?

Tags: sorting, arraylist, quicksort

Can someone help me figure out the arraylist equivalent for this block of code? There's a global "Riders" arraylist in this class, which is where the object is coming from. The swap method is one part to a larger quickSort method.

```
public void swap(int left, int right){
    Riders temp = riders[left];
    riders[left] = riders[right];
    riders[right] = temp;
}
```

I tried the .set() method, which made my code look something like this:

```
public void swap(int left, int right){
    Riders temp = riders.get(left);
    riders.set(left, riders.get(right));
    riders.set(right, temp);
}
```

But that didn't seem to sort my data, so I'm still not sure I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: Your error is somewhere else. This part is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the gem for you [Collections.swap()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap-java.util.List-int-int-)